# Setting NULL for all nullable columns in SQL

Tags: sql-server, loops, database-cursor

I have the following issue: An earlier version of a database used value '' instead of NULL. I now have to convert these values everywhere they exist into NULL if the column is nullable.

I've tried the following code:

```
BEGIN TRAN
DECLARE 
    @curcolumn VARCHAR(MAX),
    @curtable VARCHAR(MAX);

DECLARE cursor_setnull CURSOR
FOR SELECT INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES.TABLE_NAME, INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS.COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS ON INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES.TABLE_NAME = INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS.TABLE_NAME
WHERE INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS.IS_NULLABLE = 'YES'

OPEN cursor_setnull

FETCH NEXT FROM cursor_setnull INTO
    @curcolumn,
    @curtable;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        FETCH NEXT FROM cursor_setnull INTO
            @curcolumn,
            @curtable;
        DECLARE @numrows INT;
        DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(MAX);
        set @query = 'UPDATE '+@curtable+' SET '+@curcolumn+' = NULL WHERE '+@curcolumn+' = '''''
        EXEC sp_executesql @query
    END;

CLOSE cursor_setnull;
DEALLOCATE cursor_setnull;
ROLLBACK
```

At run, it gives the following errors for each column: "Invalid object name 'column_name'.

I would very much appreciate if anyone could spot the error for me.

Comment: What version of SQL Server?

Comment: As this requires updating every row multiple times, it's not a very good approach. Generating queries that update all columns at once would be better. I suspect Larnu's asking for the version exactly to know whether `STRING_AGG` is available for this task.

Comment: *"I suspect Larnu's asking for the version exactly to know whether STRING_AGG is available for this task"* bingo, @JeroenMostert . I assumed "yes" due to a lack on contrary information (though I do demonstrate how to use `FOR XML PATH` too, due to not being about to nest `STRING_AGG`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than use a `CURSOR`, I'd go for doing to whole lot in a batch with some explicit transactions. I *assume* SQL Server 2017+, due to a lack to lack of reply when I asked what version you are using:

```sql
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX),
        @CRLF nchar(2) = NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10);

DECLARE @Delimiter nvarchar(10) = N',' + @CRLF + N'    ' 

SET @SQL = STUFF((SELECT @CRLF + N'BEGIN TRANSACTION;' + @CRLF +
                         N'    UPDATE ' + QUOTENAME(s.[name]) + N'.' + QUOTENAME(t.[name]) + @CRLF + 
                         N'    SET ' + (SELECT STRING_AGG(QUOTENAME(c.[name]) + N' = CASE ' + QUOTENAME(c.[name]) + N' WHEN '''' THEN NULL ELSE '+ QUOTENAME(c.[name]) + N' END',@Delimiter) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY c.column_id)
                                        FROM sys.columns c
                                             JOIN sys.types ct ON c.system_type_id = ct.system_type_id
                                        WHERE c.object_id = t.object_id
                                          AND ct.[name] IN ('varchar','nvarchar','char','nchar')
                                          AND c.is_nullable = 1
                                          AND c.is_computed = 0) + N';' + @CRLF + 
                        N'COMMIT TRANSACTION'
                  FROM sys.schemas s
                       JOIN sys.tables t ON s.schema_id = t.SCHEMA_ID
                  WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
                                FROM sys.columns c
                                     JOIN sys.types ct ON c.system_type_id = ct.system_type_id
                                WHERE c.object_id = t.object_id
                                AND ct.[name] IN ('varchar','nvarchar','char','nchar')
                                AND c.is_nullable = 1
                                AND c.is_computed = 0)
                  ORDER BY s.schema_id, t.object_id
                  FOR XML PATH(N''),TYPE).value('(./text())[1]','nvarchar(MAX)'),1,2,N'');

PRINT @SQL; --Your best friend

--EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL; --Uncomment to run dynamic statement.
```

Comment: Just a comment: casting as NVARCHAR(MAX) inside the STRING_AGG-function will deal with the error on exceeding 8000-bit, if anyone tries this.

Comment: That *does* mean you have around 30+ columns in a single table defined as a string type and is nulllable though, @RoyM . :)

Comment: Yes, in fact I have that in multiple tables. Should it cause any issues? I have not noticed any errors or mistakes after testing around a bit.

Comment: It doesn't cause issue, no, my point is that it just means you have tables that are wider than I expected with the majority being optional string data types, @RoyM .

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the generated queries you see that the queries are inccorect.

You need to change the order you fetch values into the cursor.

```
FETCH NEXT FROM cursor_setnull INTO
    @curcolumn,
    @curtable;
```

should be

```
FETCH NEXT FROM cursor_setnull INTO
    @curtable,    
    @curcolumn;
```

Comment: Thank you for spotting an error. I mistakenly introduced this while toying around with the variable @curtable not being "declared" in the inner function. At first I thought there were some logic missing (; - , or the like), so I switched them around to test the parser-logic only and forgot this.